# Print ArrayList from another Class

Tags: java, class, arraylist

Evening everyone,

I am writing a code to allow students to search for internships. I have a class for Semesters, a class for Students(where student input is taken and stored into an ArrayList and the actual iSearch class. My code is basically doing everything I need it to do, except I have hit a brain block in trying to figure out the best way to output my ArrayList from the Student class out at the end of my program in the iSearch Class.

I am fairly new to Java, so if I haven't explained this correctly please let me know. I am trying to get the ArrayList's of student information to output at the end of the while loop in the iSearch Class.....so

To make this easy. Is it possible to print an Arraylist from another class.

Comment: I don't understand why someone can rank negative to a question, but not input feedback for improvement or help to the actual question.

Comment: Since you asked for a feedback here are some tips. Java is the one of the most object [oriented language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), I would suggest to create a Student class that has firstName, lastName and interest attributes. Then in your main create an ArrayList of Students (`ArrayList<Student> students;`).
Concerning your `iSearch` class, it is really painful to read it since the code is not really clean. Start by cleaning up your model, then fix your main and finally come and update the question. Best of luck (=

Comment: The best way to print an array list is `System.out.println(myArrayList);`. It's not very clear where you're stuck or what your question is.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried so far and we will guide you to a better solution

Answer (score 0):

A better way to solve this is to create a Student object for each student. In your current class the ArrayLists you are creating are deleted after every method call, since it is not referenced anymore.

Here is how I would do it:

Student Class:

```
public class Student {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String interest;


    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String interest) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.interest = interest;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public String getInterest() {
        return interest;
    }

}
```

In your iSearch class you create an ArrayList of students, which lets you add your students:

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    do {
        String firstName = input.next();
        String lastName = input.next();
        String interest = input.next();
        students.add(new Student(firstName, lastName, interest));
    } while (YOUR_CONDITION);
```

Then you can display each student by iterating through the ArrayList and accessing the getter and setter methods:

```
    students.foreach(student -> {
        System.out.println(student.getFirstName());
        System.out.println(student.getLastName());
        System.out.println(student.getInterest());
    });
```

Editing this a little will help you to solve your problem, but this is the basic solution.